# New Amazon music streaming service and Nyquist sampling theorem

Tags: dac, sampling

I read [this](https://www.theverge.com/2019/4/26/18518182/amazon-music-service-cd-quality-hi-fi-tidal-competitor-unlimited-prime-price) story on The Verge the other day,

> “It’s a better bitrate, better than CD quality,” said one of MBW’s sources, indicating the new service will put Amazon in direct competition with Tidal’s $20-a-month hi-res streaming tier. Tidal is able to offer these “Master” quality recordings, thanks to a partnership with hi-res music technology company MQA, although Amazon is reportedly intending to offer a better bitrate than CDs without a similar partnership.

I'm a bit confused about this. Based Nyquist's theorem a sampling rate of anything greater than 40 kHz should be enough to reproduce a signal that has a bandwidth upto 20 kHz, which I assume is 99.999% of the listening public.

Given that CDs are sampled at 44.1KHz, is it fair to assume that CDs carry the best possible audio quality discernable to the human ear?

If yes, then isn't this just a marketing gimmick?

Comment: Voting to close this as _too broad_ but maybe I should have chosen _opinion based_. This question always just lead to dozens of audiophile flamewars and everything there is to write about sound quality vs. sample rate has been debated to death since the eighties.

Comment: See the [Xiph video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cIQ9IXSUzuM) for proof that CD is good enough. And www.audiocheck.net to see if you can hear that high, or test your speakers.

Comment: Although I agree with the comments above, the claim is about the **bit**rate. Your argument is solely based on the sample rate. Bitrate doesn't directly translate to sample rate, since it also takes the resolution into account. I mean, if you listen to 5bit 44KHz music, you'll certainly notice it's crap. So to prove your point, you need to explain both 1) that 44KHz sampling rate is enough, but also 2) that 16bit/sample is enough (you didn't do that last part).

Comment: And to further complicate things, bit rate is just one important factor, there is also DAC width (resolution/dynamic range) and compression errors.

Comment: For a good background on bit depth and sample rate _before_ compression even comes into play, check out the video [_Digital Audio: The Line Between Audiophiles and Audiofools_](https://youtu.be/IiZqYnd5g8M) by Mark Furneaux.

Comment: The noise floor (the distortion floor, the trash floor) of 24-bit music on single-guitar decays is audibly cleaner --- "sounds live" --- compared to 16 bit music. This was on Allman Brothers Elizabeth Reed. On other hand, in very busy music, difficult to tell difference between 24 and 16 bits

Answer (score 6):

Bit rate should not be confused with sample rate.

Other things being equal, a higher bit rate mean more bits per sample, which means less noise energy per sample added due to the quantisation process.

Nyquist says only that you need more than 2x the bandwidth to reconstruct the original sampled waveform. He is silent on *how much more* you need. The more in excess of 2x the bandwidth you have available, the less work you need to do when anti-alias or reconstruction filtering. A reconstruction filter from 48kHz (a common digital music DAC rate) requires about half the resources that one from 44.1kHz needs, as resources scale by roughly the reciprocal of the width of the transition band. Alternatively, this could mean that, for the same resources, the filter from 48kHz can be made 'better' than one from 44.1kHz.

Those are facts. When we get into subjective audio quality, and whether 20 bits actually sounds better than 16, or 96kHz sounds better than 44.1, then opinions generally prevent rational discussion. However, 'more stuff' generally does help shift product into some sectors of the market.

For the record though, when I was making some vinyl to CD transfers for my Mother, and cleaning up surface noise and muting between tracks in Audacity, I was very surprised to find that a 30dB SNR was all that I needed to hear music as essentially 'noise free'. That's me though, I've probably grown a bit cloth-eared with my increasing age.

Answer (score 2):

The comment in the article is not about sampling theorem or Nyquist, it's about the compression algorithms they're using. They're just saying that their new service will run at a higher bitrate than the industry-standard 256 kbps or 320 kbps, and that it will sound "better than CD quality", which is actually a very subjective statement.

The designers of compression algorithms can make a variety of choices regarding tradeoffs between sample resolution, bandwidth and the specific distortions that the lossy compression introduces. In general, if you run a given algorithm at a higher bitrate, it sounds better.